# Can we add buttons in a "popup event on click" button?

Tags: html, css, button, popup

Can I have a popup when i click on a button let's say download button. And the popup should contain various buttons which gets me to some other pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, there are several methods for this.

But the simplest way to achieve this is with CSS MODALS. A modal is a dialog box/popup window that is displayed on top of the current page. Here you can include as many extra buttons as you wish.

For further information please see:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp